# Joomla 2.5 website gone down, any ideas

Tags: joomla

one of my sites has gone down this morning. It has been up and running fine for over a year, it is giving the error message:

1146 - Table 'connect2.ilwrn_contentitem_tag_map' doesn't exist SQL=SELECT `m`.`tag_id`,`t`.* FROM `ilwrn_contentitem_tag_map` AS m INNER JOIN `ilwrn_tags` AS t ON `m`.`tag_id` = `t`.`id` WHERE `m`.`type_alias` = 'com_content.article' AND `m`.`content_item_id` = 35 AND `t`.`published` = 1 AND t.access IN (1,1)

The site is: www.connect2recruit.com

Neither the site of the backend are working, had a look around but cannot find anything obvious on the server.

Any help would be appriciated as my client is not very happy.

Regards

Paul

Comment: Disable components via PHPMyAdmin until the site works again, then re-enable all but the last one. Then tell us what it was. Instructions: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2144391&sid=19d1bcc320c3e13e18aef9bee8c1a59f#p2144391

Comment: Also, Joomla 2.5 is no longer supported. Now might be the time to rectify that.

Comment: The first thing to check is whether that table actually exists, is it possible you have database corruption? Also are you self hosting or is it possible your host did something that caused the change to happen?